# Rake Task with Cron Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake

I am trying to set up cron job to run a rake task daily. I currently have the following cron job (note, the time is all *'s because I want it to run every minute while testing)

```
* * * * * cd /home/jon/thestockenator/lib/tasks/ && ./get_current_data.sh
```

In the shell script I added the entire PATH to whatever the path is when cron runs it and call rake test_task.

I set up a basic rake task that simply outputs some text (because my real one takes a while to run)

```
task :test_task do
    puts "this is a rake task"
end
```

The cron job definitely runs and `which rake` works when run in the cron job.

Comment: I guess your rake task from cron is not getting executed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this to the script:

`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`